# Namenode recovery, How does namenode recovery works?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

In `hadoop` ecosystem we have `NameNode` and `SecondaryNameNode`, `NameNode` is responsible to managing all data available in cluster, So my question is when `NameNode` goes down how ecosystem replace and recover it with other `NameNode`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 things to be considered here,

```
1- Recovery through SecondaryNameNode
2- Recovery through redundant NameNode
```

In `hadoop-1.x` we have the concept on SecondaryNameNode which holds a copy of the NameNode metadata. If your NameNode goes down you can take the metadata copy stored with SecondaryNameNode and use it to resume your work, once your NameNode is up again.

With `hadoop-2.x(HA)` you can have more than 1 NameNode. In case primary NameNode goes down, the redundant NameNode can take over so that your cluster doesn't stop working(either manual or automatic). In this implementation there is a pair of NameNodes in an active/standby configuration. In the event of the failure of the active namenode, the standby
takes over its duties to continue servicing client requests.

In order to take advantage of HA feature, you should run the NameNodes in HA mode with a quorum of journalling nodes, or a shared HA-NFS storage for the edit log transaction files. I would suggest you to go through these posts which explain the recovery mechanisms beautifully :

1- http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/05/namenode-recovery-tools-for-the-hadoop-distributed-file-system/

2- http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/10/quorum-based-journaling-in-cdh4-1/

3- http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/03/high-availability-for-the-hadoop-distributed-file-system-hdfs/

But if you are on hadoop-1.x, you are better off having 2 separate locations for storing NameNode metadata(one drive on the machine itself+1 NAS).

HTH

Comment: Well explained. Can you please elaborate the Recovery through SecondaryNamenode in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38629642/namenode-failure-recovery-hadoop-1-0-4